# The standalone Bootstrap 4 navbar on another non bootstrap website

Tags: bootstrap-4

How to use the standalone Bootstrap 4 navbar  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/  on another non bootstrap existing web site?

If I import bootstrap CSS styles and JS, it change all the appearance of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_navbar.scss and all its dependencies to your poject.

Also you could find that you need some of those files https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev/js/src .

I know that this is not the answer you want. You want some distribution package, but it is absent. I'm just trying to interesting you with bootstrap internals. Do not afraid to copy open source to your projects - that is why it is open source.